# how to parse a custom json in php

Tags: php, json

I have a json value like this :

```
 {
    "A":{"id":"1","checked":false},
    "B":{"id":"2","checked":true},
    "C":{"id":"3","checked":true}
}
```

I just need `id` and `checked` values. I don't know what value is placed in `A`,`B`,`C`.

```
        $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($chboxs, TRUE)),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
            if(is_array($val)) {
               // echo "$key:\n";
            } else {
                //echo "$key => $val\n";
                if($val == true){
                    $val = 1 ;
                }else{
                    $val = 0 ;
                }
                $ch = array();
                $ch['isvisible'] = $val;

                $this->m_general->edit('coupon_properties' , $ch , array('id'=>$key));
            }
        }
```

It doesn't work fine.

Comment: Take a look at: `json_decode()` + `array_column()`

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$arr = json_decode('{
    "A":{"id":"1","checked":false},
    "B":{"id":"2","checked":true},
    "C":{"id":"3","checked":true}
}');
```

So this will give you as:

```
Array (
  A => Array (
    id => 1,
    checked => false
  )
  B => ...
)
```

You can get it like:

```
$arr["A"]["id"];      // 1
$arr["B"]["checked"]; // true
```

So, to iterate, you can use:

```
foreach ($arr as $ar) {
  echo $ar["id"], $ar["checked"];
}
```

Comment: I do not know what value is placed on A,B,C .

Comment: @S.M_Emamian What is your desired output?

Comment: echo `$id ` and echo `$value;`